# Order of Execution of packages and script with npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

What is the order of execution when we use npm install.

As of now when I use npm install, It looks like-

1. dev dependencies
2. preinstall script
3. dependencies
4. install
5. postinstall

But in different condition it behave differently.
What is correct order of Execution?

Comment: you can study here to find what's happening when you run npm! https://npm.github.io/how-npm-works-docs/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as of [npm doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts) the order is:

**prepare** (since npm@4.0.0)

Runs BEFORE the package is packed, i.e. during npm publish and npm pack

Runs on local npm install without any arguments

Runs AFTER prepublish, but BEFORE prepublishOnly

**prepublish** (DEPRECATED)

Does not run during npm publish, but does run during npm ci and npm install. See below for more info.

**prepublishOnly**

Runs BEFORE the package is prepared and packed, ONLY on npm publish.

**prepack**

Runs BEFORE a tarball is packed (on "npm pack", "npm publish", and when installing a git dependency).
NOTE: "npm run pack" is NOT the same as "npm pack". "npm run pack" is an arbitrary user defined script name, where as, "npm pack" is a CLI defined command.

**postpack**

Runs AFTER the tarball has been generated but before it is moved to its final destination (if at all, publish does not save the tarball locally)

**dependencies**

Runs AFTER any operations that modify the node_modules directory IF changes occurred.
Does NOT run in global mode

---

Note that this is in addition to the pre and post scripts.

To create "pre" or "post" scripts for any scripts defined in the "scripts" section of the package.json, simply create another script with a matching name and add "pre" or "post" to the beginning of them.

eg.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "precompress": "{{ executes BEFORE the `compress` script }}",
    "compress": "{{ run command to compress files }}",
    "postcompress": "{{ executes AFTER `compress` script }}"
  }
}
```